# The <div> attached to a button is not showing when I move the button to another position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Video of the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P4DUlgVjWFT8ciWhJGBnHLrfgyD_pLY7/view)

**PLEASE WATCH THE VIDEO TO KNOW MORE ABOUT THE ISSUE!**

This `<div>` should be visible when I hover the button,

```
<div class="layer55">
  <h3>
    <table class="testingTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="testingTH"> Name </th>
          <th class="testingTH"> Phone Number </th>
          <th class="testingTH"> Job Type </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="testingTD"> John Wick Travolta </td>

          <td class="testingTD"> 0000000000 </td>

          <td class="testingTD"> Mercenary </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <center>
            <img class="center" src="John.jpg" alt="John" height="121" width="155" />
          </center>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </h3>
</div>
```

This is the code to make the `<div>` visible when I hover the button :

```
.pos1:hover ~ .layer55 {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

I'm positioning my button, let's say at...

```
top: 6.25%;
left: 30%;
```

but when I move the button (my page has dragging feature) to another position, let's say at...

```
top: 6.25%;
left: 10%;
```

The `<div>` is not showing, because it stayed at the first position, `top: 6.25%; left: 30%;`, instead of the latest position, which is at `top: 6.25%; left: 10%;`

This is the full **HTML** code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title> Testing Employee Recognition System </title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="testerCSS.css"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="testerT.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bgCSS">
      <section>
        <div class="pos1">
          <div data-draggable="target">
            <button data-draggable="item">
              <font> John </font>
              <font> Wick </font>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

<!--- STAFF INFO ------->

        <div class="layer55">
          <h3>
            <table class="testingTable">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th class="testingTH"> Name </th>
                  <th class="testingTH"> Phone Number </th>
                  <th class="testingTH"> Job Type </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td class="testingTD"> John Wick Travolta </td>

                  <td class="testingTD"> 0000000000 </td>

                  <td class="testingTD"> Mercenary </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <center>
                    <img class="center" src="John.jpg" alt="John" height="121" width="155" />
                  </center>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </h3>
        </div>

<!-- EMPTY SLOT POSITION -->

        <div class="pos110">
          <div data-draggable="target">

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div> <!-- End of class bgCSS -->
  </body>

  <script src="testerJS.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is the full **CSS** code :

```
/* canvas styles */
.bgCSS {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background : linear-gradient(to right, rgba(67, 137, 162, 0.75), rgba(92, 37, 141, 0.75));
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 2s;
}

button {
  border-radius: 7px;
}

font {
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

body
{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* ----- STAFF DESKS POSITION ----- */
section .pos1 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 6.25%;
  left: 30%;
}

/* ----- STAFF HOVER EFFECTS ----- */

section:hover button {
    filter: blur(5px);
    transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out;
}

section button:hover {
    transition: background 0.25s;
    filter: blur(0px);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #4d2800;
}

/* ----- STAFF INFO ----- */

section .layer55 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 31.25%;
  left: 70.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #d9f4f5;
  background: rgb(232, 227, 240);
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* ----- DRAG ITEM & TARGET ----- */

/* draggable targets */
[data-draggable="target"]
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;

    width:135px;
    height:40px;

    border:1px solid #888;

    background:#ddd;
    color:#555;
}

/* drop target state */
[data-draggable="target"][aria-dropeffect="move"]
{
    border-color:#68b;

    background:#fff;
}

/* drop target focus and dragover state */
[data-draggable="target"][aria-dropeffect="move"]:focus,
[data-draggable="target"][aria-dropeffect="move"].dragover
{
    outline:none;

    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 3px #68b;
}

/* draggable items */
[data-draggable="item"]
{
  background-color: rgba(22, 19, 19, 1);
  background-position: center;

    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;

  width:135px;
    height:40px;
}

/* items focus state */
[data-draggable="item"]:focus
{
    outline:none;

    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #68b, inset 0 0 0 1px #ddd;
}

/* items grabbed state */
[data-draggable="item"][aria-grabbed="true"]
{
    background: grey;
    color:#fff;
}

/* ----- STAFF HOVER DATA ----- */
.pos1:hover ~ .layer55 {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

/* ----- EMPTY SLOT POSITION ----- */

section .pos110 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.25%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

And this is the full **JS** code :

```
(function()
{

    //exclude older browsers by the features we need them to support
    //and legacy opera explicitly so we don't waste time on a dead browser
    if
    (
        !document.querySelectorAll
        ||
        !('draggable' in document.createElement('span'))
        ||
        window.opera
    )
    { return; }

    //get the collection of draggable targets and add their draggable attribute
    for(var
        targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="target"]'),
        len = targets.length,
        i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'none');
    }

    //get the collection of draggable items and add their draggable attributes
    for(var
        items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="item"]'),
        len = items.length,
        i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        items[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
        items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
    }



    //dictionary for storing the selections data
    //comprising an array of the currently selected items
    //a reference to the selected items' owning container
    //and a refernce to the current drop target container
    var selections =
    {
        items      : [],
        owner      : null,
        droptarget : null
    };

    //function for selecting an item
    function addSelection(item)
    {
        //if the owner reference is still null, set it to this item's parent
        //so that further selection is only allowed within the same container
        if(!selections.owner)
        {
            selections.owner = item.parentNode;
        }

        //or if that's already happened then compare it with this item's parent
        //and if they're not the same container, return to prevent selection
        else if(selections.owner != item.parentNode)
        {
            return;
        }

        //set this item's grabbed state
        item.setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'true');

        //add it to the items array
        selections.items.push(item);
    }

    //function for unselecting an item
    function removeSelection(item)
    {
        //reset this item's grabbed state
        item.setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');

        //then find and remove this item from the existing items array
        for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if(selections.items[i] == item)
            {
                selections.items.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //function for resetting all selections
    function clearSelections()
    {
        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //reset the owner reference
            selections.owner = null;

            //reset the grabbed state on every selected item
            for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                selections.items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
            }

            //then reset the items array
            selections.items = [];
        }
    }

    //shorctut function for testing whether a selection modifier is pressed
    function hasModifier(e)
    {
        return (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey);
    }


    //function for applying dropeffect to the target containers
    function addDropeffects()
    {
        //apply aria-dropeffect and tabindex to all targets apart from the owner
        for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if
            (
                targets[i] != selections.owner
                &&
                targets[i].getAttribute('aria-dropeffect') == 'none'
            )
            {
                targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'move');
                targets[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
            }
        }

        //remove aria-grabbed and tabindex from all items inside those containers
        for(var len = items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if
            (
                items[i].parentNode != selections.owner
                &&
                items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed')
            )
            {
                items[i].removeAttribute('aria-grabbed');
                items[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
            }
        }
    }

    //function for removing dropeffect from the target containers
    function clearDropeffects()
    {
        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //reset aria-dropeffect and remove tabindex from all targets
            for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                if(targets[i].getAttribute('aria-dropeffect') != 'none')
                {
                    targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'none');
                    targets[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
                }
            }

            //restore aria-grabbed and tabindex to all selectable items
            //without changing the grabbed value of any existing selected items
            for(var len = items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                if(!items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed'))
                {
                    items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
                    items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
                }
                else if(items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
                {
                    items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //shortcut function for identifying an event element's target container
    function getContainer(element)
    {
        do
        {
            if(element.nodeType == 1 && element.getAttribute('aria-dropeffect'))
            {
                return element;
            }
        }
        while(element = element.parentNode);

        return null;
    }



    //mousedown event to implement single selection
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a draggable item
        if(e.target.getAttribute('draggable'))
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //if the multiple selection modifier is not pressed
            //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
            if
            (
                !hasModifier(e)
                &&
                e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false'
            )
            {
                //clear all existing selections
                clearSelections();

                //then add this new selection
                addSelection(e.target);
            }
        }

        //else [if the element is anything else]
        //and the selection modifier is not pressed
        else if(!hasModifier(e))
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //clear all existing selections
            clearSelections();
        }

        //else [if the element is anything else and the modifier is pressed]
        else
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();
        }

    }, false);

    //mouseup event to implement multiple selection
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a draggable item
        //and the multipler selection modifier is pressed
        if(e.target.getAttribute('draggable') && hasModifier(e))
        {
            //if the item's grabbed state is currently true
            if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
            {
                //unselect this item
                removeSelection(e.target);

                //if that was the only selected item
                //then reset the owner container reference
                if(!selections.items.length)
                {
                    selections.owner = null;
                }
            }

            //else [if the item's grabbed state is false]
            else
            {
                //add this additional selection
                addSelection(e.target);
            }
        }

    }, false);

    //dragstart event to initiate mouse dragging
    document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e)
    {
        //if the element's parent is not the owner, then block this event
        if(selections.owner != e.target.parentNode)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        //[else] if the multiple selection modifier is pressed
        //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
        if
        (
            hasModifier(e)
            &&
            e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false'
        )
        {
            //add this additional selection
            addSelection(e.target);
        }

        //we don't need the transfer data, but we have to define something
        //otherwise the drop action won't work at all in firefox
        //most browsers support the proper mime-type syntax, eg. "text/plain"
        //but we have to use this incorrect syntax for the benefit of IE10+
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');

        //apply dropeffect to the target containers
        addDropeffects();

    }, false);



    //keydown event to implement selection and abort
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a grabbable item
        if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed'))
        {
            //Space is the selection or unselection keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 32)
            {
                //if the multiple selection modifier is pressed
                if(hasModifier(e))
                {
                    //if the item's grabbed state is currently true
                    if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
                    {
                        //if this is the only selected item, clear dropeffect
                        //from the target containers, which we must do first
                        //in case subsequent unselection sets owner to null
                        if(selections.items.length == 1)
                        {
                            clearDropeffects();
                        }

                        //unselect this item
                        removeSelection(e.target);

                        //if we have any selections
                        //apply dropeffect to the target containers,
                        //in case earlier selections were made by mouse
                        if(selections.items.length)
                        {
                            addDropeffects();
                        }

                        //if that was the only selected item
                        //then reset the owner container reference
                        if(!selections.items.length)
                        {
                            selections.owner = null;
                        }
                    }

                    //else [if its grabbed state is currently false]
                    else
                    {
                        //add this additional selection
                        addSelection(e.target);

                        //apply dropeffect to the target containers
                        addDropeffects();
                    }
                }

                //else [if the multiple selection modifier is not pressed]
                //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
                else if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false')
                {
                    //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                    clearDropeffects();

                    //clear all existing selections
                    clearSelections();

                    //add this new selection
                    addSelection(e.target);

                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers
                    addDropeffects();
                }

                //else [if modifier is not pressed and grabbed is already true]
                else
                {
                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers
                    addDropeffects();
                }

                //then prevent default to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            //Modifier + M is the end-of-selection keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 77 && hasModifier(e))
            {
                //if we have any selected items
                if(selections.items.length)
                {
                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers
                    //in case earlier selections were made by mouse
                    addDropeffects();

                    //if the owner container is the last one, focus the first one
                    if(selections.owner == targets[targets.length - 1])
                    {
                        targets[0].focus();
                    }

                    //else [if it's not the last one], find and focus the next one
                    else
                    {
                        for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
                        {
                            if(selections.owner == targets[i])
                            {
                                targets[i + 1].focus();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //then prevent default to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        //Escape is the abort keystroke (for any target element)
        if(e.keyCode == 27)
        {
            //if we have any selected items
            if(selections.items.length)
            {
                //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                clearDropeffects();

                //then set focus back on the last item that was selected, which is
                //necessary because we've removed tabindex from the current focus
                selections.items[selections.items.length - 1].focus();

                //clear all existing selections
                clearSelections();

                //but don't prevent default so that native actions can still occur
            }
        }

    }, false);



    //related variable is needed to maintain a reference to the
    //dragleave's relatedTarget, since it doesn't have e.relatedTarget
    var related = null;

    //dragenter event to set that variable
    document.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e)
    {
        related = e.target;

    }, false);

    //dragleave event to maintain target highlighting using that variable
    document.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e)
    {
        //get a drop target reference from the relatedTarget
        var droptarget = getContainer(related);

        //if the target is the owner then it's not a valid drop target
        if(droptarget == selections.owner)
        {
            droptarget = null;
        }

        //if the drop target is different from the last stored reference
        //(or we have one of those references but not the other one)
        if(droptarget != selections.droptarget)
        {
            //if we have a saved reference, clear its existing dragover class
            if(selections.droptarget)
            {
                selections.droptarget.className =
                    selections.droptarget.className.replace(/ dragover/g, '');
            }

            //apply the dragover class to the new drop target reference
            if(droptarget)
            {
                droptarget.className += ' dragover';
            }

            //then save that reference for next time
            selections.droptarget = droptarget;
        }

    }, false);

    //dragover event to allow the drag by preventing its default
    document.addEventListener('dragover', function(e)
    {
        //if we have any selected items, allow them to be dragged
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }, false);



    //dragend event to implement items being validly dropped into targets,
    //or invalidly dropped elsewhere, and to clean-up the interface either way
    document.addEventListener('dragend', function(e)
    {
        //if we have a valid drop target reference
        //(which implies that we have some selected items)
        if(selections.droptarget)
        {
            //append the selected items to the end of the target container
            for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                selections.droptarget.appendChild(selections.items[i]);
            }

            //prevent default to allow the action
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //if we have a valid drop target reference
            if(selections.droptarget)
            {
                //reset the selections array
                clearSelections();

                //reset the target's dragover class
                selections.droptarget.className =
                    selections.droptarget.className.replace(/ dragover/g, '');

                //reset the target reference
                selections.droptarget = null;
            }
        }

    }, false);



    //keydown event to implement items being dropped into targets
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a drop target container
        if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-dropeffect'))
        {
            //Enter or Modifier + M is the drop keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 13 || (e.keyCode == 77 && hasModifier(e)))
            {
                //append the selected items to the end of the target container
                for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
                {
                    e.target.appendChild(selections.items[i]);
                }

                //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                clearDropeffects();

                //then set focus back on the last item that was selected, which is
                //necessary because we've removed tabindex from the current focus
                selections.items[selections.items.length - 1].focus();

                //reset the selections array
                clearSelections();

                //prevent default to to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    }, false);

})();
```

**How do I make the div attached to the button wherever the button moves?**

Comment: using z-index and position attributes may work for you here

Comment: This is the video to explain it more vaguely

[GD Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P4DUlgVjWFT8ciWhJGBnHLrfgyD_pLY7/view?usp=sharing)

@Yahiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you drag your button `<div class="pos1">` to target `<div class="pos110">` it goes behind the target, so the hover effect did not work as expected. This can be solved by increasing the `z-index` of the `.pos1` element,

```
section .pos1 {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 10;
    top: 6.25%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: This is the video to explain it to you the problem 

[GD Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P4DUlgVjWFT8ciWhJGBnHLrfgyD_pLY7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @hycarlDev_, dragging feature is not working here to test, did we miss some referencing js file?

Comment: I don't quite understand, I've pasted all the codes for JS and as you can see in the video, that's the problem

Comment: @hycarlDev_, dragging feature is now working. This is happing as the visibility is related to `.pos1:hover` but not on the button, which will be moved to a new position. You may bind the visibility on the button hover or add some class to `.pos1` or `.pos110` when it has the child button and then applies the hover effect on that class.